# media9: toggle elements of a 3D scene

Tags: 3d, media9

I successfully created a 3D PRC file and have embedded it in a PDF using LaTeX and the `media9` package.
Now I need to create buttons to allow the user to toggle on/off some elements of the scene.
From the `media9` manual I guess I can do that using the `\mediabutton` and `jsaction`.
But I am ignorant of Javascript commands and could not figure how to use the `jsaction`.
Hope someone can give me an example of media button command to toggle one or several elements of the 3D scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires some JavaScript.

Below example uses the PRC file `epix.prc` from the `media9` package. The initialization script `init3D.js` defines the method

```
toggleNodeByID(<id>)
```

that recursively toggles the visibility of all children belonging to the node identified by its `<id>` (an integer number).

In order to determine a node `<id>`, an auxiliary script `getID.js` is provided. Click the part in question in the "Model Tree" navigation pane of A-Reader. The ID is then printed into the console. After finalizing the document, the line

```
add3Djscript=getID.js,
```

can be removed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{filecontents}

%%%%%%% 3D initialisation script %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Defines method toggleNodeByID(<ID>) for toggling %
% node visibility.                                 %
% <ID> to be determined by using the auxiliary     %
% script `getID.js' listed below.                  %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{filecontents*}{init3D.js}
  toggleNodeByID = function (i) {
    if(scene.nodes.getByIndex(i).firstChild)
      toggleSubNode(scene.nodes.getByIndex(i).firstChild);
    else
      scene.nodes.getByIndex(i).visible=!scene.nodes.getByIndex(i).visible;
    return;
  }
  toggleSubNode = function (nd) {
    if(nd.nextSibling) toggleSubNode(nd.nextSibling);
    if(nd.firstChild) toggleSubNode(nd.firstChild);
    else nd.visible=!nd.visible;
  }
\end{filecontents*}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%% 3D-JS for getting node ID %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Only needed during document authoring.           %
% In the Model Tree, click the part to get its ID. %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{filecontents*}{getID.js}
  selEventHandler=new SelectionEventHandler();
  selEventHandler.onEvent=function(e){
    if(e.selected){
      for(var i=0; i<scene.nodes.count; i++) {
        if (scene.nodes.getByIndex(i)==e.node) {
          host.console.show();
          host.console.println("Node ID: "+i);
        }  
      }
    }  
  }  
  runtime.addEventHandler(selEventHandler);
\end{filecontents*}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\includemedia[
  label=example3D,
  width=0.8\linewidth,
  add3Djscript=init3D.js,
  add3Djscript=getID.js, %remove this after finalizing the document
  add3Djscript=asylabels.js,  %upright text labels
  activate=pageopen,
  3Dmenu,
  3Dc2c=4 2 3,
  3Dcoo=4.4 2.2 0,
  3Droo=430,
  width=0.6\linewidth, height=0.6\linewidth
]{}{epix.prc}

\mediabutton[
  jsaction=example3D:{
    annotRM['example3D'].context3D.toggleNodeByID(2);
  }  
]{\fbox{\strut surface}}

\mediabutton[
  jsaction=example3D:{
    annotRM['example3D'].context3D.toggleNodeByID(71);
    annotRM['example3D'].context3D.toggleNodeByID(105);
  }  
]{\fbox{\strut x axis}}

\mediabutton[
  jsaction=example3D:{
    annotRM['example3D'].context3D.toggleNodeByID(3);
    annotRM['example3D'].context3D.toggleNodeByID(37);
  }  
]{\fbox{\strut y axis}}

\mediabutton[
  jsaction=example3D:{
    annotRM['example3D'].context3D.toggleNodeByID(143);
    annotRM['example3D'].context3D.toggleNodeByID(177);
  }  
]{\fbox{\strut z axis}}

\mediabutton[
  jsaction=example3D:{
    annotRM['example3D'].context3D.toggleNodeByID(215);
  }  
]{\fbox{\strut function label}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Terrific, this is exactly what I need! Now I have a small problem to implement this solution: the `<name>` from the "Model Tree" are duplicated... Could I use the UTF16NAME instead? If so, what would be the syntax?

Comment: I realise my question is silly: UTF16NAME are just a translation of the `<name>` to hex... Is there a solution to my problem? If several elements have the same name, how can I select one of them?

Comment: @Herve I  rewrote the script, to toggle part visibility by Node ID. This is more robust than identifying the Node by regular expression. To determine the Node ID, use the auxiliary script `getID.js`.

Comment: Fantastic! Now it works! That solves my problem, thank you so much AlexG!